# Как удалить беседу (delete conversation) через Telegram API BOT

Tags: php, java, telegram-bot, telegram

В приложение Telegram есть кнопка **Delete conversation**.
В TELEGRAM API есть возможность удалить беседу?

Comment: определитесь, какой именно апи нужен?

Answer (score 1):

В *Bot API* такой возможности **нет**. В *Telegram API* есть возможность **очистить историю сообщений** с помощью метода [messages.deleteHistory](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.deleteHistory), но удалить диалог - **нет**.